# Route mappings are broken suddenly. How to fix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Route mappings for my MVC app are broken suddenly.

Here are route mappings

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Here is controller code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string Login()
    {
        return "Login";
    }
}
```

I can access Index view by using http://localhost:49637/ but I cannot access Login view via http://localhost:49637/Login. If I try to access Login view via http://localhost:49637/Home/Login, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no route that matches - 'http://localhost:49637/Login' as your only route looks for both a controller and an action value, and you are only passing one value, so MVC is attempting to route you to a 'Login' controller that does not exist. I haven't tested this, but adding something like this should fix your problem-

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Login",
    "Login",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
);
```

Remember that asp.net MVC will use the first matching route it finds, so you'll need to place this route above the 'default' route in your `RegisterRoutes` function.

Comment: I've just find out the problem. It was caused my poor knowledge about MVC. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Mark his answer as right, if you think it solved your problem.